# Will there be conflict if there is two account with the same domain?

Tags: domains, dns, server

What will happen if more than one account on the same server is using the same domain? For instance in shared hosting, I have two user using the same domain name (Add-ons). Since this two accounts are on the same server, the domain is pointed to the same nameserver, will there be a conflict? and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one account can "win" (probably the one defined first in the server's config), so yes there will be a conflict.

> and how to resolve this?

- Remove the domain from the account in error. (*Preferred.*)
- Ensure that the correct account is defined first in the server config.

---

On the other hand, if you are on a shared server and using some kind of front end control panel (eg. cPanel, Plesk) then it's quite possible that the duplicate could be rejected at the time of creation, thus avoiding the conflict to begin with? (*Not tried this.*)